# flutter app foreground launcher icon size exceeds

Tags: flutter, dart

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcherIcon/logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcherIcon/logo.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FF0000"
  adaptive_icon_padding: true
```

I'm new to flutter.I tried to update app launcher icon in flutter but app foreground image size exceed the size when background color is added.its a demo image.  help please

[image: foreground exceed image][image: its a demo image background color hex code is not as in the code]

Answer (score 1):

The images generated in the android folder should be deleted

[image]

Then you must regenerate them

Comment: Thanks,I used Android Studio Image asset file to create .png icons and copied the created res folder...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to give your logo image some padding like if your logo is 70X70 make it in 100x100 with at least 30% margin, you can do it easily In illustrator.

Comment: Thanks,Now I am able create the launcher icon from image asset in Android studio , also using this package will try with a image with background color included ,so that additional color no need to add, appreciate your help